# Django - Adding model without default ModelAdmin permissions (add, change, delete, view)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-permissions

I am facing problems with adding simply new permission to admin panel

In my **models.py** i have:

```
class search_hostname(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = [("search_hostname", "Can search hostname")]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.application
```

but after makemigrations and migrate in my admin page i get "Can search hostname" and other four default:

```
app | search_hostname | Can add search_hostname
app | search_hostname | Can change search_hostname
app | search_hostname | Can delete search_hostname
app | search_hostname | Can view search_hostname
app | search_hostname | Can search hostname
```

i have no old migrations which would cause this

is there any way to avoud adding those default permissions and have only **Can search hostname** in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute [`permissions` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#permissions) is used for *extra* permissions on top of the default permissions that Django will make. If you don't want the default permissions or want to modify them, you need to set [`default_permissions` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#default-permissions):

```
class search_hostname(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = [("search_hostname", "Can search hostname")]
        default_permissions = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.application
```

Comment: If default_permissions = [] was added after migration, how to clear permissions already in db ?

Comment: @luzik that's a separate question please use the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.